# Are the claims about repeating states and space in Netflix's "A Trip to Infinity"'s based on real research?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, spacetime, universe, poincare-recurrence

I just watched Netflix's documentary on infinity ["A trip to infinity"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt21929356/). They have an example where you put an apple in a perfectly sealed box. They make a claim that seems odd to me.

The apple will decay etc etc but because there are a finite number of possible states for the contents in the box, it must eventually reach a state it was in before (all good up to here) and so it will eventually become an apple again.

Why must it eventually become an apple again? It will enter a cycle but there's no need for that cycle to contain the initial state. Wouldn't the cycle would very likely be a cycle through a bunch of states of very high entropy?

Similarly they claim that if the universe is infinite, then our region of space must be repeated an finite number of times elsewhere. Why? Does something force a repeat of *our* region? Sure, *some* region might repeat but it doesn't have to be an interesting region.

Are there papers/theorems behind these claims that forces repeats to be "interesting"?

They have some serious scientists in the documentary, so it would be weird for this to be completely wrong.

Comment: I haven't seen that doco, but it sounds like there's a *lot* of rubbish in it, mixed in with some good stuff based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem It may have correct stuff stated in interviews with reputable scientists, but that doesn't mean that all the contents were given proper scrutiny by qualified scientists & mathematicians.

Comment: Thanks. I guess they were referring to that, so at least the apple in a box one has a basis. I wonder does the infinite universe one have a basis. I don't see what forces the repeated regions of space to be close to anything in particular.

Comment: I had the same reaction that you did, but I gave up on watching it about halfway through.

Comment: "...because there are a finite number of possible states for the contents in the box..." I think they assumed that space is discrete, not continuous, in order to make the number of possible states finite.

Comment: @D. Halsey not necessarily, the number of states of a system of set energy and size should be finite regardless (e.g. the Bekenstein bound).

Comment: The paper the scene is based on: https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0417

Comment: That's a very boring modern day take on the Poincare Recurrence theorem, which was mildly entertaining in the 19th century... roughly around the time when the flying skirts of the Can-can dancers in Paris were "mildly shocking". The simple fact is that there there are no perfectly closed boxes and there is no "infinite" space, either. Serious science doesn't care about intellectual nonsense like that.

Comment: @FlatterMann: *Serious science doesn't care about intellectual nonsense like that.* – Thoughts experiments like these can be very revealing about how the universe work and lead to useful applications. If we did not make them, we would often be stuck with impossibly tedious problems. For example, while nothing is truly infinite, introducing the notion of infinity (and infinitesimality) considerably eases solving a lot of actual problems, e.g., whenever you apply calculus.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thought experiments are teaching tools. All they do is to make it easier for students to form an intuition about scientific facts. The Poincare recurrence theorem and its modern variations are not scientific facts. They are pure fiction without any physical meaning. One can easily show that many important Hamiltonian systems don't obey the theorem at all. All non-trivial gravitationally bound systems are violating it, for instance.

Comment: I saw the documentary and was surprised. Why isn't anyone talking about the 2nd law of Thermo? Isn't it the case that the matter in the box has to take a one way path to higher entropy? In the show it turned into a clock, a statue, a mouse, etc. But the 2nd law says it would just keep homogenizing into a meaningless stateless soup, am I right?

Comment: 2nd law is probabilistic, there are vastly more paths to higher entropy than to lower but if toss a coin forever, the chances of no run of heads > N is zero for all N.

My beef with this is that they are claiming you will get specific outcomes.

I guess if you throw quantum jumps in there then, it can always break out of any well or any boring cycle.

Comment: Related:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429330/poincar%c3%a9-recurrence-and-its-implications-for-statistical-physics-and-the-arrow-o/429385#429385

Answer (score 9):

As far as I can tell, the apple claim refers to the [ergodic hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_hypothesis), which implies that each microstate of a system will be assumed over time. In the apple example, the macrostate is the box containing a given collection of atoms with a given energy. The apple being whole is one microstate and thus it will need to be assumed again by the ergodic hypothesis.

Now, the ergodic hypothesis is, well, only a hypothesis. It is impossible to empirically check as such, but we use it as the foundation of statistical mechanics, from which several empirically confirmed statements are derived. Also, all known toy systems that break the ergodic hypothesis are somewhat pathological and I see no reason to assume that the apple system is one of them.

If we assume true quantum randomness, we can see how the apple might become whole again: It is possible to find a chain of state transitions from every given state to the apple being whole: Atoms just need to collide with each other in a given way. This chain is admittedly very unlikely to happen, but the probability is not total zero. Thus if you wait long enough, it will eventually happen, though you cannot say when. (Mind that this doesn’t prove ergodicity as that would require showing that all states are equally likely.)

You might compare this to applying random transformations to a [Rubik’s cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube): Most of the time, you will get an unsolved cube, but there clearly is a chain of transformations that solves the cube from any given state¹. Thus if you apply random transformations long enough, you will obtain the solved cube. Also, all possible configurations of the cube are clearly equally likely, including the solved one. Mind that if you have a deterministic chain of transformations, it may not ever visit the solution, but a random one is bound to.

¹ I here assume that the cube has not been tampered with, e.g., by prying out an edge stone and flipping it.

> Wouldn't the cycle would very likely be a cycle through a bunch of states of very high entropy?

The thing about entropy maximisation is that it is only a statistical statement, i.e., it only holds when looking at large ensembles of particles (or similar) and only with a probability that is sufficiently close to one to assume it to be true for all practical purposes.
The apple example destroys the underlying assumptions by waiting an infinite amount of time.

Comment: The ergodic hypothesis is not exactly a hypothesis, either. It is for instance not valid for an ideal gas. Neither is it valid for systems with few degrees of freedom. It is certainly not valid for Newtonian n-particle systems. I would not be surprised if somebody proves one day that it is only valid for a sparse subset of all possible systems.

Comment: @FlatterMann: I don’t claim to be an expert on the current state of the ergodic hypothesis, but for example the kind of violation I am aware of for ideal gases (and that I can find on a quick search) is hinging on the ideality of the gas, namely that particles don’t interact at all, thus allowing them to be locked in quasiperiodic motion or similar. This is pretty pathologic in my book.

Comment: It may be pathological but it still invalidates the hypothesis. The trivial example of gravitating n-particle system kills the applicability in the real world completely. It's a nice fantasy for certain applications, but that is all it is.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bogus claim.

If we imagine that the apple rots out to its constituent atoms, and those atoms form a gas, there will be instants in time where a few of the hydrogen atoms come close to an oxygen and a few carbons all at the same spot, and the result of that fluke is that for a microsecond, the transient agglomeration of those atoms vaguely resembles a sugar molecule- before those atoms go their own way. Then you wait a year before it happens again.

(And for that apple to reconstitute itself, the constituent molecules have to be put together out of atoms, which requires energy. With no energy input to the box, you can't build molecules.)

Now notice that in an apple there are about 10^23 atoms, and that there is only one right way to put all of them together again into a duplicate of the original apple. There are, on the other hand, a truly huge (but finite!) number of wrong ways to put those atoms together, none of which even vaguely resembles an apple. How huge?

Pick an atom, one out of 10^23. Pick another at random; your chance of getting the next one right is one out of (10^23 - 1). The chance of getting the next one right is one out of (10^23 - 2), and so on until you have chosen every atom correctly to exactly reconstitute every molecule in the original apple. The cumulative probability is going to look  like one out of  (10^23) x (10^23 - 1) x (10^23 - 2) x (10^23 - 3) x ..., *repeated 10^23 times*.

Just the first four terms give you a probability of one chance in 10^102, for comparison there are only about 10^80 fundamental particles in the entire universe.

This means that reconstituting the same apple out of randomly picked atoms will essentially never never never never never happen- especially if you do not provide the energy input necessary to build the molecules. So the claim is bogus.

Comment: OK, that is my understanding too, however it's a show about infinity, so highly improbably is not enough. If there is some reason to believe that the box must move through *all* possible states in a cycle then it will happen. My understanding is that it must enter a cycle eventually but that cycle does not have to include the initial states.

But really I'm asking if there is some paper than says, counter-intuitively - that I'm wrong.

Comment: @FergalDaly  Nobody has ever seen infinity. It's a mathematical concept, not a physical one. Even within mathematics there are serious doubts about it.

Comment: Also, the box is assumed to be perfectly sealed, which I assume to include energy. Thus, all the energy required to reassemble the apple is there.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yes, but even in that case we are more likely to see a cherry and a small portion of vanilla pudding, instead.

Comment: @FlatterMann: *Even within mathematics there are serious doubts about it.* – This statement suggest a misunderstanding about how mathematics works. Mathematics doesn’t try to determine whether infinity exists or not. There are just some axiom systems which allow for introducing something like infinity as a useful shorthand for *sufficiently large.* And this is also how it used in this example. While there are some mathematicians who try to figure out what happens in systems where you cannot have such a notion of infinity, this does not mean that they “doubt infinity” (nor “believe” in it).

Comment: @FlatterMann: *Yes, but even in that case we are more likely to see a cherry and a small portion of vanilla pudding, instead.* – Indeed, but so what? This does not diminish the claim in question.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Exactly. So absolutely nothing. Intellectual nonsense is intellectual nonsense.

Comment: @FlatterMann: I have no idea what your last comment is referring to.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft The problem with infinity in mathematics is not "existence" in a physical sense. The question is whether infinity is well defined. Sufficiently large is not what mathematicians mean by infinity. No finite set is sufficiently large to map out the real numbers for instance and even countable sets are not enough. If you follow that reasoning you will find that mathematicians have enormous problems with constructing a consistent theory of infinities.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I was referring to your comment "Indeed, but so what?". Indeed so nothing. Language allows us to talk all day long about things that have never existed and that will never exist. That is what the fiction section of the library was invented for... all the talk about fictional things, like perfectly isolated boxes that replicate apples after eons of time.

Comment: @FlatterMann I'm not sure what enormous problems you are referring to. There certainly *were* a lot of problems before Cantor and modern set theory.

Comment: @FergalDaly You are in the physics stack exchange. We don't have sets here and even if we did, they wouldn't be infinite. Cantor has zero application in physics.

Comment: @FlatterMann: You were the one starting to talk about pure mathematics (“constructing a consistent theory of infinities”) on Physics SE. You can’t make claims about mathematics and then reflect any criticism and request for clarification by referring to this being Physics SE.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I gave a trivial and well known example from mathematics where something infinite doesn't repeat itself. That is as far as I will take it in the physics section. My suggestion to inform yourself about the deeper problems of infinity in mathematics is something that you can take up in your own time if you like. You will find out that it is not trivial and that it is not solved. That's all there is to say about it HERE.

Comment: You appear to forget that infinity absolutely DWARVES that number.  The point is, in a hypothetical isolated box (the universe) that exists for infinite time, all possible microstates that can happen WILL happen.  Not only that but they will occur an infinite number of times.

Answer (score -2):

I have not seen the referenced documentary but seemingly 'absurd' claims like you have mentioned can be made because infinity is *absurdly large*.

If we do not care whether it is allowed by the laws of physics or not, every arrangement of a group of atoms has to be repeated infinite number of times in a collection of infinite number of atoms.**#** So if the universe is infinite, every place - which is a particular arrangement of atoms - will repeat infinite number of times. Leave just one such configuration, you fall short of infinity.

Similarly, if we wait for infinite time and the atoms in the apple keep on rearranging randomly, we will get every arrangement of atoms - including the arrangement of atoms in the original state of the apple - infinite number of times.

I think such claims are made just to emphasize the largeness of infinity. They consider just the statistics, the physics may have something else to say.

EDIT:

**#** Perhaps this sentence is not conveying what I intend to say so I am trying to rephrase/explain it in brief.

To make a collection of atoms infinite we have to add every possible combination of atoms into it. If we leave any such combination, we fall short of infinity. Not only this, every combination of atoms has to be repeated till it can not be repeated any further - if there really comes such a point after which the combination can not be repeated further. This means, we have to add every combination of atoms 'infinite' number of times. [Use of 'infinite' to describe infinity may make the concept cyclic but here it is to convey just the idea mentioned before.]

Of course, we are talking about [absolute infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_Infinite) which is just an idea developed by mathematicians. Physically, we can not achieve infinity. Number of atoms in the universe is not infinite and physics imposes restrictions on how atoms can be arranged. But when we are discussing just the 'idea', we need to consider every possible combination of atoms 'infinite' number of times to achieve the infinity.

Comment: The claim that an infinite set has to repeat patterns is false. See the decimal representation of pi as a trivial counterexample, for instance. It never repeats itself.

Comment: You may be right in what you say but what I've written is different. Firstly, I'm not considering a 'set' but a 'collection' in which entities can repeat any number of times. Secondly, the configuration of the entities considered is 'random'. The arrangement of digits in the decimal representation of pi is not random. Of course, the arrangement of first n digits will never start repeating no matter how large n we consider for that will make pi rational number which it is not. But I'm not aware that it has been proved that no combination of digits in the decimal expression of pi can ever repeat

Comment: It's better if down votes are supported by comments.

Comment: It is simply false to say that infinity has the power to repeat whatever we want to have repeated. It's false in physics (infinity does not exist) and it's false in mathematics. The Poincare Recurrence Theorem doesn't even claim a repeat. It claims an "almost repeat". Of course, once you look at real physical systems, even idealized ones, you will notice that the assumptions of the theorem are almost never fulfilled to begin with. Gravitating systems, for instance, do not have a finite phase space volume.

Comment: *It's false in physics* Yes, perhaps. *it's false in mathematics* No, for sure. I've clearly indicated in the answer that 'They consider just the statistics, the physics may have something else to say'. Largeness of infinity is really mind boggling. We can not imagine it if we are stuck with prejudices caused by real systems or even the ideal systems considered in physics. Further, your mention of Poincare Recurrence Theorem is unnecessary. It talks about *finite* time. Anyway, I will keep my answer unchanged - notwithstanding down vote - hoping that OP and others can get its essence.

Comment: You can always take this question to the mathematics stack exchange. I am pretty sure that you will get some highly interesting answers there, too.. but probably not the ones that you are expecting. You are also welcome to evaluate the Poincare recurrence time on your own for some simple multi-particle systems. Again you will find that it all just amounts to intellectual nonsense.

Comment: 'intellectual nonsense' seems to be your favorite catchphrase. :) Mine is, 'some people *know* more than what they *understand*'. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion for taking this to mathematics stack exchange.

Comment: The "intellectual nonsense" doesn't come from me. It comes from my first theoretical physics professor. He told us about the Poincare Recurrence Theorem in form of a Christmas story in the last class before the winter break. The man had a really good sense of humor, for sure, and he taught a rock solid classical mechanics class.

Comment: I don't get the essence because you seem to be making basically the same claim. I don't see what forces anything interesting to be repeated. You could have a lump of interesting stuff in one region and then repeat low-density emptiness off to infinity.

Comment: *You could have a lump of interesting stuff in one region and then repeat low-density emptiness off to infinity.* Suppose you have done so and you think you have reached infinity. Now start adding the 'interesting stuff' repeatedly. Can you? If you had already reached infinity with your low density emptiness, where this extra 'interesting stuff' is going? The point is that you don't make it infinite until you have added every combination infinite many times. You say, that's absurd. And that is infinity.

Comment: *I don't get the essence because you seem to be making basically the same claim.* I did not know that I should not 'be making basically the same claim' and I needed to prove them bogus. :) Anyway, I've not made any claim from my side. I was just trying to give a perspective with which you could see the point of such claims which, I think, are made in the documentary just to emphasize the vastness of infinity.

Comment: _"every arrangement of a group of atoms has to be repeated infinite number of times in a collection of infinite number of atoms"_ makes three probably-false assumptions: 1. The number of possible arrangements is countably-infinite; 2. Every possible arrangement has a finite probability of occurring; 3. every group is **independent** from all other groups.